# Why strike stones taken from inside a pot against each other?

Tags: culture, the-eccentric-family

In Episode 10 of Uchouten Kazoku (5:34), I saw Shimogamo Mother taking two stones from a pot, and striking them against each other before Shimogamo Yaichirou went out.

[image: Two stones in pot.]

What does it mean? Is it some kind of supernatural belief?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Japanese folklore, creating sparks by striking flint is considered to be lucky for someone leaving a house or group. The brief fire was once a way to drive evil spirits away. I found a reference to it being called [*kiribi*](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2010/12/16/reference/kiribi/#.Ulr0hJmTZ8E), but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of information on it.

Considering where Yaichiro is going as he leaves, it would be logical for a mother to wish her son good luck and to drive away evil from his path.

[image: The flint is struck together to make a spark.]

This ritual is not common anymore, but given the spiritual nature of *Uchouten Kazoku*, it makes perfect sense.